# CakePHP 4 - support for named parameters?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I looked at the CakePHP 4 docs and noticed, that the support for named parameters via `Router::parseNamedParams` is removed.

I have an application where I make heavy use of named parameters and any other way would definitely make everything much more complicated.

Is there a practical way to use named params in Cake 4 or am I out of luck and have to stay at 3.x?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from writing your own bit of middleware based on the 3.x implementation. Just to be clear, though, you're talking about urls like `https://example.com/things/thing:5/option:yes/page:6`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Those are from 2.x, in 3.x they also dont exist anymore for a reason. They are not HTTP compliant.

Comment: Good point. But if someone has tons of old links out there, they might want to support them for a while to prevent 404ing their visitors.

Comment: @GregSchmidt yup, I'm talking about these. In Cake 4 these are not supported anymore. I dont need them for any public sites, but for a pretty big API I am using and the effort to implement all the stuff in a different way currently makes no sense - especially since nothing of this is for public use. Maybe you can point me in the right direction (Cake Docs?) of how to implement a middleware for this?

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/middleware.html#creating-middleware